# How to filter logs via processImagePath?

Tags: macos, logs

Given the following log entries (which I run in other Terminal to compare my filter):

```
$ log stream --level debug | grep -w Google
Activity    0x80000000003a7a20   75676  Google Chrome Helper: (CoreFoundation) Loading Preferences From System CFPrefsD For Search List
Debug       0x0                  75676  Google Chrome Helper: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.CFBundle.resources] Resource lookup at <private>
Debug       0x0                  11599  Google Chrome: (Security) [com.apple.securityd.handleobj] create 0x7fd130d2677a for 0x7fd130d262e0
```

<sup>Note: Removed datetime column for above example for better visibility.</sup>

Now I'd like to filter log based on the *Google* keyword to display log entries from *Google Chrome Helper*, *Google Chrome* and *Chromium* processes.

However the following command doesn't display these entries:

```
$ log stream --level debug --predicate 'processImagePath contains Google'
Filtering the log data using "processImagePath CONTAINS Google"
Timestamp                       Thread     Type        Activity             PID
```

---

I'm following the `man log` docs page logic as per this example:

```
$ log show --predicate 'processImagePath endswith "hidd" and senderImagePath contains[cd] "IOKit"' --info

Timestamp                       Thread     Type        Activity     PID
2016-06-10 13:54:34.593220-0700 0x250      Info        0x0          113    hidd: (IOKit) [com.apple.iohid.default] Loaded 6 HID plugins
```

---

What I'm doing wrong? Why `processImagePath contains Google` filter isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per *Apple* support response, string constants must be quoted within the predicate expression.

So the command should have syntax like:

```
log stream --level debug --predicate 'processImagePath contains "Google"'
```

See: [Creating a Predicate Using a Format String](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html) at *Apple Programming Guide*.