# How do I use `log stream` to search ALL existent logs on macOS for strings?

Tags: command-line, logs

I need to search all logs on macOS Mojave for "some string".  I was told that the way to do this was to execute:

```
sudo log stream --source --start'1999-99-99 23:59' | egrep -i "some regex string"
```

However this isn't doing the trick.  What's the appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No support for `--start`

The usage guidances for `log stream` give no indications that a `--start` argument is supported, I wonder if they were talking about `log show` instead.

*log stream usage*

```
$ log stream --source --start
log: unrecognized option `--start'
usage: log stream [options]
   or: log stream [options] --process <pid> | <process>

description:
    Stream events from the system or a given process.

options:
    --color <mode>                  Control color output (valid: auto, always, none)
    --level default | info | debug  Include events at, and below, the given level
    --predicate <predicate>         Filter events using the given predicate
    --process <pid> | <process>     Stream events from the specified process
    --source                        Annotate output with source file and line-number
    --style <style>                 Output format (valid: syslog, json, compact)
    --timeout <num>[m|h|d]          Terminate streaming after timeout has elapsed
    --type activity | log | trace   Limit streaming to a given event type
    --mach-continuous-time          Print mach continuous time timestamps rather than walltime

predicate usage:
    Filter predicates follow the NSPredicate format described at:
    https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html

    For predicate field/type details, see `log help predicates`.
```

#### Using `log show`

`log show` has a `--start` switch which you can use as follows:

```
$ log show --source --start '2019-01-01' | egrep -i "some regex string"
```

**NOTE:** This can be a very expensive command to run since it'll be going through all the logs on your system from that `--start` time, but will return all the matches to your `egrep`.

#### Streaming logs

The use of `log show` will stop once it encounters the end of the logs. If you truly want to analyze/filter the stream of logs as they occur then you'll want to use `log stream` like this:

```
$ log stream --source | grep -iE "some regex string"
```

-or-

```
$ log stream --source --predicate 'processImagePath contains "some bit of text"'
```

#### References

- [How to filter logs via processImagePath?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301685/how-to-filter-logs-via-processimagepath)
- [log man page](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/log.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use `zgrep` to recursively (`-R`) search the logs directory (`/var/log`), though it doesn't handle Apple's `asl` format so nicely e.g.

```
zgrep -R that_thing /var/log
```